# html class is not working in css? (despite the correct syntax)

Tags: css, html

I created a class and attached a CSS file and targeted it with the code, and although it changes the color of the highlight class it doesn't change the current class'es color. What may be the problem?

```css
header .highlight, 
header.current a {        
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1><span class="highlight">A</span>NİLİZ</h1>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="Aniliz.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
      <li><a href="hakkımızda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="Anilizler.html">Anilizler</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `header.current` is looking for `<header class=“current”>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give space b/w `header` and `.current`

```css
header .highlight, 
header .current a {        
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1><span class="highlight">A</span>NİLİZ</h1>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="Aniliz.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
      <li><a href="hakkımızda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="Anilizler.html">Anilizler</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm speechless... not putting one space cost me three hours of frustration. Ty the code worked after I put the space in between.

Comment: That's css for you. Good Luck coding.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your CSS more closely.

```
header .highlight, 
header.current a {        
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This translates to something along the lines of:

> For any child element of `<header>` with the class name `.highlight`
>   and any anchor link within a `<header>` with class `.current` apply
>   the following styles

Based on your description it sounds like you need to change it to be:

```
header .highlight,
header .current a {
  ...
}
```

That space between `header` and `.current` is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize the code you are having trouble with. The only problem I see is in the css in the html, the  tags are spelled correctly. But in the css it looks like you used Header .highlight, header . current a, twice. it should be

header.highlight, header .current a {
color: #e8491d:
font-weight: bold;